# Hyphen getting replaced by symbol while importing data in python

Tags: python, jupyter, symbols

So, I am trying to import some text data in Python which are of the following type:

TRV

GW – Complex Work

GW – Complex Work

GW – Complex Work

GW – Complex Work

But instead I am getting text as

TRV
GW � Complex Work

GW � Complex Work

GW � Complex Work

GW � Complex Work

Tried to replace the symbol with space- did not work. Any suggestion son how to remove the symbol? Or better, how to import the data without the long hyphen getting mutated into a symbol?

Comment: How do you know that's what you're getting? Where is it being displayed? See how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely occurred due to improper encoding. Try to use following code snippet to read file using utf8 encoding or use can replace encoding of your choices.

```
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    text = f.read()
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried encoding cp1252 and it worked.